# Firebase java package in jruby

Tags: jruby

I'm attempting to use firebase's newly open sourced [java firebase-admin sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java) with jruby. The firebase docs have the following instructions for initialization in java:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

First time attempting to use jruby. I've loaded up the firebase package using jbuilder. Having some trouble accessing these initialization methods. Need some guidance on translating this from java to jruby.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out

```
class FirebaseInstance
  attr_accessor :options, :app
  include_package 'com.google.firebase'
  include_package 'com.google.firebase.auth'

  def initialize
    @options = set_options
    @app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(@options)
  end

  def set_options
    builder = FirebaseOptions::Builder.new
    builder.setDatabaseUrl(<URL>)
    builder.setCredential(credentials)
    builder.build
  end

  def credentials
    service_account = Java.JavaIo.FileInputStream.new(<FILE LOCATION>)
    credentials = FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(service_account)
  end
end
```